# Cast TextureRegion to TextureRegion

Tags: java, android, sprite, andengine

i am developing a game like fruit ninja in which currently i am using only one fruits name facebook 
and developing pool for fruits now the pool is ready but when i define

```
      1. private TextureRegion facebook;
      2.    facebook = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
      3.            this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "facebook.png", 0, 0);


      4.    target = new TargetsPool(facebook);
```

in my simplebasegameactivity is gives error on line 4       target = new TargetsPool(facebook); and says change type of facebook to TextureRegion  when i go for it a code

```
       org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion
```

generates in place of TextureRegion in line 1

```
 public class TargetsPool extends GenericPool<Sprite> {

private TextureRegion mTextureRegion;

public TargetsPool(TextureRegion facebook) {
    if (facebook == null) {
        // Need to be able to create a Sprite so the Pool needs to have a
        // TextureRegion
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The texture region must not be NULL");
    }
    mTextureRegion = facebook;

}



@Override
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem() {

        Sprite sprite =new Sprite(0, 0, mTextureRegion.deepCopy());



    return sprite;
}

protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Sprite target) {
    target.clearEntityModifiers();
    target.clearUpdateHandlers();
    target.setVisible(false);
    target.detachSelf();
    target.reset();
}
```

}

it is a cast problem which i generally get when i use andengine some time org.anddev.andengie  works sometime org.andengine this works.

Comment: do you get a ClassCastException?

Comment: hmm. all my andengine packages are org.andengine not org.anddev.andengine...  i would keep that consistent.  if i remember right, org.anddev.andengine is the prefix of andengine GLES1 packages, but im not 100% sure on that. otherwise, your code looks correct. you can find the GLES2 branch here: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

Comment: can i use both GLES1 and GLES2 in one class

Comment: Do not mix GLES1 and GLES2.